# MS Access 2013 query query criteria can't assess if value A is contained in value B string

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Issue: 
I am developing a simple issue tracking database and have hit a stumbling block that I’m not sure how to resolve. Have tried several approaches using queries, sql statement etc but still not working. I may have to rethink how I am doing this but hoping someone may be able to address the issue as it stands, though if a more elegant way of doing it happy to implement that.

Scenario:
A table called tblUsers has a field called Access that is a lookup to a table called tblCategory and allows for multiple values to be stored (one to many). In essence this is saying which category(s) of “issue” the user is allowed to

A simple msgbox test in code shows that this is correctly storing the values selected in the following format "1, 2, 3, 4"

In turn, each issue can only have a single category (one to one) which is stored in a field called Category in table tblGMPIssues and is also populated from a lookup to the tblCategory table.

So far so good ….

I then have a query called qryUserIssues that should show all issues from the table tblGMPIssues that are a) “Open” (status = 1) and that b) match any of the categories that the user is permitted to view.

I can get this to work with a single value i.e. as it stands query prompts for input and if you enter a single valid integer it returns expected results

But I can’t work out the syntax to get the criteria to accommodate multiple values. For example, in above scenario our user should be allowed to see 4 different category or calls “1, 2, 3, 4”

Tried using INNER joins, tried assigning to variables and using a LIKE criteria but can’t seem to get the syntax right.

If anyone could let me know if this can be done and if so how as it’s driving me nuts.

All help and suggestions gratefully received.

Updated relationship diagram --> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N3pE.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: @Andy, can you give me SQL of the query that you are trying. You had taken screen shot in Design Mode of Query, there is one SQL button clicking the same you will get SQL statement of the query. I can suggest you solution.

Comment: IssueID IssueStatus IssueUserID IssueDate Expr1004 IssueType IssueSeverity IssueLocation IssueDescription IssueCategory      
8 1 1 28/01/2017 3 2 3 3 fdghdfg         3
16 1 2 28/01/2017 4 1 3 4 xcvncvbn         4
19 1 1 29/01/2017 5 2 3 2 dfxgbxcvbnxcv 5
25 1 2 29/01/2017 6 1 2 6 cvbncvb         6
28 1 2 29/01/2017 7 4 5 5 bncvbn         6
29 1 2 26/01/2017 8 3 5 3 cvbncvb         8

10th column of data represent the calls category value, so the query would be for arguments sake to return all issues with a value of 6.

Comment: the current sql query i have so far that return ALL issues is 

SELECT tblIssues.IssueID, tblIssues.IssueStatus, tblIssues.IssueUserID, tblIssues.IssueDate, tblIssues.IssueCategory, tblIssues.IssueType, tblIssues.IssueSeverity, tblIssues.IssueLocation, tblIssues.IssueDescription, tblIssues.IssueCategory
FROM tblIssues
WHERE (((tblIssues.IssueStatus)="1"));

Answer (score 2):

For precisely the reason that you've asked this question I would recommend **never** using the multi-select lookup option for columns in MS Access tables. Instead create an intersection table which tells you the combinations of values from the two main tables that are allowed. So instead of having the multi-select `Access` column in `tblUsers`, you should have a separate table called `tblUserAccess` with two columns (`UserID` and `CategoryID`). The two columns together will form a composite Primary Key for this table, and individually they will be Foreign Keys to `tblUsers` and `tblCategory` respectively. (You should do the same kind of thing with `tblType` - remove the `Categories` column and set up a separate table called `tblTypeCategories`).

Coming to your query, are you expecting this to show you all the relevant Issues for a particular user? At the moment, it is not doing this. The reason it is prompting you for input is because it doesn't understand `([tblUsers].[Access])` - `tblUsers` is not referenced in your query, and the query has no way of knowing which particular user you're interested in.

With your new table in place (and populated with the relevant data) you should add `tblUserAccess` to the query, joining `tblGMPIssues.Category` to `tblUserAccess.CategoryID`. Take the `([tblUsers].[Access])` condition off the `Category` column. Add the `UserID` column to the grid and set the criteria to `[Input UserID]`. Now when you run the query it will ask you for a user ID, and it should hopefully show you all the Issues that the given user can access.

Good luck!

Comment: Trying to implement it this evening makes more sense now that it's been explained. It's purely my lack of Access knowledge that led me to do it the way i had previosuly.

Comment: Hi Skippy, Thansk for the excellent feedback ... didn't get a chance to do the other day but taking a look at it now. I have created the to intersection tables but seems to only allow one or the other to be the primary key and can't form composite so just need to have a readup around thisas must be somethign i'm doing wrong. Much appreciated for theassistance.

Comment: Nevermind me being a dolt - sorted and shows structure as suggested so will redo the query later this evening and see if it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you normalize your data a bit:

- You have a number of tables that are reference data (e.g. tables `tblStatus`, `tblSeverity`, `tblLocation`). You have a s a primary key a (system generated) `ID`. That is *wrong*! The primary key of these should be their data, i.e. status, severity, location.
- I can't see what the relationships are between the data. It should be one-to-many, mandatory (i.e. one `Status` can occur in many `tblGMPIssues` and a status is mandatory).
- Your table `tblType` is unclear to me but it contains the categories. I am not familiar with the '-' before Categories followed by a `Categories.Value` but I assume an occurrence of `tblType` can contain exactly one `Categories.Value`. If not, then you must decompose this table.
- If a User has access to a number of Categories, then there must be a many-to-many relationship betwen Users and Categories. From this relationship you do your select query, but I don't see this relationship.

Comment: Comments on your answer (I will need to split across multiple comments to reply in full). 1. Why is a (system generated) ID wrong? I can see advantages for doing this. If you have a query that is written to look for a particular status (e.g. 'Open') and you subsequently decide to rename this status as 'In Progress' then your query suddenly stops working. If you use StatusID = 1 then it doesn't matter what name you  give to the status, the query will always work. Also, I believe that joins on numeric fields are more efficient than joins on text fields (but I could be wrong on this point.

Comment: 2. I think this version of Access lost the '1' and 'many' indicators in the Relationships diagram for some reason. Given that we can see the PK values on the reference table we can probably assume that the one-many relationships are right, but yes, it's worth checking this. 3. The '-' before Categories is a bad feature of Access that allows you to store multiple values from a lookup table is one column. This feature should never be used, and instead you should define the intersection table yourself (which I think Access does behind the scenes anyway).

Comment: 4. Point 3 explains why you're not seeing the many-many relationships (same with the Access column on Users table). They are implicitly there, but for writing queries this way of doing it makes life really complicated.

Comment: Ad 1: reference data should only be referenced by its value. A system generated ID would allow duplicates of the reference data (e.g. `ID=1, status='OK'` and `ID=9, status='OK'`). Use `UPDATE CASCADES` of the foreign key so the name change will cascade to the child table. And ignore efficiency on small data sets.

Comment: I still have a problem with the relationship of `tblCategory` with all the other tables: I see no logic in it. I actually only see cycles in it. You want to model that users have acess to categories and that a problem is of a certain catagory. But I don't see that.

Comment: Oh, important for Ad 1`: you can inspect the data without having to look up IDs in other tables to find their values.

Comment: Ad 1: I am not arguing that you should never use reference data as the PK on the reference table. I just disagree with your assertion that to use an ID is ("always" implied) wrong. Yes, cascade update will update child tables, but this will not update hard-coded criteria in queries or values in VBA code (or any other code that accesses the data). Duplicate reference data can be avoided by specifying the data column as Unique. As for having to look up IDs in other tables to find their values - it's a relational database; there does tend to be quite a bit of that looking up kind of activity.

Comment: I can sort of see where OP is coming from with the Categories, but agree that the table structure is confusing and could lead to data inconsistencies. tblGMPIssues could have a Category set that does not agree with the Categories available for the Type that has been set.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. It is my lack of knowledge that'sleading me to make these mistakes. Sounds like there's a number of ways i could have done this better but rather than start from scratchagain will try the intersection tables. Ihave reworked DB to tighten up on naming conventions, PK,data types and removed all the auto LOOKUP fields. below is an updated image of the tables and structure i think if i read above comments about intersection tables correctly should be ok.

Comment: Updated relationship diagram on original call

Comment: Looks better, but I am still confused about Type and Category. Does a Category have a Type or is a Type of a Category? You must still remove the multi-valued attributes as they are managed by relations.

Answer (score 0):

Use following query to get any of the Category IDs 1, 2, 3 or 4

```
Select * from tblGMPIssues where tblGMPIssues.Category in (Select UserAccess from tblUserAccess)
```

Comment: ok, but with above it won't alwaysbe "(1,2,3,4)" so can this be done with  the actual values of the logged in user on the system so user A logs in and his IssueAccess multi value is 1,4,7,8 so he sees all call with a category value of 1,4,7,8. User B logs in andhas IssueAccess mutivalue of 1,2,9 so can only see these category calls.

Comment: So could the query be : ----
Select * from tblGMPIssues where tblGMPIssues.Category in (tblUsers.UserAccess.Values)

Answer (score 0):

I still have many problems with your relational design, or actually the *lack* of a proper relational design. As an example, below is a diagram from my Access 2007 showing a part of your database with a proper design. Access automatically shows that "one" and "many" symbols (which I don't see in your diagrams). I also show the relationship dialog with the proper fields checked. Note that *none* of the keys of any table, except tblIssue, has a system generated primary key. They are all plain text whch allows better understanding when inspecting the data and, as said, the database automaticlly updates child tables when the primary key value of a parent table changes.

Note table tblCategoryType: it implements a many-to-many relation between categories and types, meaning a category can be of zero or more types and a type can be in zero or more categories. In addition to "update cascades", this table has the "delete cascades" checkbox checked so if a category is deleted, all its relations with types are deleted (not the types).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Paul, My "lack" of relational design is down to inexperience and relying on Access 2013 to behave in the way Access did when i last did any work with it which was back around Acess 97. So yes it is probably an appalling state. 

The issue remains the user interface is the most elegant and easiest way for users to select which category of calls they are allowed to see. Unless you can suggest another way where user can select from list but ot store as multi vaues?

Now if Acess 2013 allows you to store multi-values my issue is why Microsoft don't easily allow you to query them?

Comment: The ER diagram not showing relationships is just how Access 2013 works ... the relationships are all one-to-many

Comment: You must be able to instruct Access to show the relationship symbols. It should work "upward better" from my 2007 to your 2013; it shouldn't work "upward worse". Pleas look for it. And note the "Enforce relational Integrity" checkbox. Are they all checked???

Comment: You can create a listbox that is populated from a query. From the relational model, that query can select exactly the categories defined for the user.